# In Jetty, how to support certificate authentication only on a subset of API

Tags: ssl, jetty, client-certificates

I'm building a web service and are using Jetty as the server. For some of the API-s this service provides, we want them to be authenticated by certificate. So I have following code:

```
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setWantClientAuth(true);

Server server = new Server(pool);
ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
        new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "HTTP/1.1"),
        new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig));

server.addConnector(sslConnector);
```

Now, my service also has a corresponding web UI. When users access the web UI which in turn calls backend API-s, the browser prompts the user for a cert. I don't want this to happen because the API called by the web UI do not support certificate authentication. However, the above code is configuring in a global way. Is there any way to resolve this ?

**Update**:

I've looked at other server implementations.
For example, in ASP.NET, we can define following config:

```
<location path="some-api">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert"/>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

There is also [similar settings](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#arbitraryclients) in Apache Http Server

So it seems SSL/TLS itself isn't prohibiting me from doing so. Are there any Jetty settings that I have missed ?

Answer (score 2):

The TLS level certificate validation occurs before the HTTP Request is even sent/processed/parsed.

It's not possible to skip that validation based on information after the TLS handshake.

You could, as an alternate method, just put the certificate validation on a different port on the same machine (with a different ServerConnector configuration), leaving the normal connector without client certificate validation.

Comment: Hi Joakim. Thanks for your answer. It turns out my organization might not allow me to build a service exposing an http port other than 443. Hence I'm thinking about it in the other direction. If I call an API from my UI code using javascript, is there a way to ask the browser to not prompt for a cert ?

Comment: My answer isn't about having another port on unsecured HTTP.  You can easily have another port on TLS+HTTP (aka HTTPS).

Comment: Hi Joakim, even HTTPS on a different port might not be allowed but I can double confirm. That said, today I learned that we have another project using ASP.NET. In that project, we are able to require cert auth only for a subset of API by the following config: `<location path="some-api"><system.webServer><security><access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert"/></security></system.webServer></location>`.

Comment: By comparing the 2 calls in Wireshark, we can see the Jetty server requests client cert during SSL handshake. But ASP.NET didn't request it during the handshake stage. Although I didn't find out, it must have requested client cert in another stage when the server already has information like the requested host, path, etc. So it seems there are different protocols for servers to request client cert. Is there a way for Jetty to achieve the same ?

Comment: Client Certs are part of the TLS handshake.  even if you switch to Kerberos the client certificates would still exchange before the Request is even sent by the client.

Comment: Joakim, you may be correct in describing TLS handshake. But that doesn't explain what I see when trying the ASP.NET project. I tried to access 2 different paths with the same host and same port in my browser - one prompted for cert while the other didn't. If that is something doable with IIS, is it also doable with Jetty without having to use multiple ports ?